# How to create animation like stack of images using javascript or GSAP as provided in the URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, gsap

I am trying to create a 3d animation using **JavaScript/jQuery** or [**GSAP**](http://greensock.com/gsap) library where I have stack of images like [**this**](http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Samsung-Galaxy-S6-Multi-view.jpg) (instead of apps which is present in android multiple app screen) and I can scroll up and down through a scroll bar.

I am trying to create a basic html page with the animation like above example. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Just for the reference, I have created a small snippet:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="image-container">
    <img src="http://elonka.com/kryptos/sanborn/KGBCyrillic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-container">
    <img src="http://elonka.com/kryptos/sanborn/KGBCyrillic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-container">
    <img src="http://elonka.com/kryptos/sanborn/KGBCyrillic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-container">
    <img src="http://elonka.com/kryptos/sanborn/KGBCyrillic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-container">
    <img src="http://elonka.com/kryptos/sanborn/KGBCyrillic.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-container">
    <img src="http://elonka.com/kryptos/sanborn/KGBCyrillic.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
 ul {
  position: relative;
}

 .image-container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
}

 .image-container img {
  width: 340px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Working demo is available at [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVrgMx). Thanks!

Comment: Your *codepen* doesn't seem to be working at all?

Comment: Hi Tahir, You have to click on the image first and start scrolling to see it

Comment: Have updated my codepen to make it work using simple jquery, currently using mousescroll the images move down using jquery animate